# circle ci module is not installed

Tags: npm, circleci, react-helmet

I have a container on circle ci that goes through all tests and does a npm install to install all packages in the package.json. But it seems some packages is not installed causing circle ci to fail

error

```
 22:24  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'react-helmet'  import/no-unresolved
```

Even dough I can see the package is in package.json

```
"react-helmet": "^5.1.3",
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like the package.json file and the circle.yml file

Answer (score 0):

Adding `npm install -g` to circle.yml fixed it